# How can I get the country name when I put the mouse on the map?

Tags: dynamic, geography, geographics

How can I get the country name when I put the mouse on the map?

```
CountryData["World", {"Shape", {"Equirectangular", {0, 180}}}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Slightly modified from the first example in the "Properties & Relations" section of the [`CountryData` entry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html):

```
GeoGraphics[{
  EdgeForm[Gray],
  Tooltip[Polygon[GeoVariant[#, "SimplifiedArea"]], CommonName[#]] & /@
    CountryData["Countries"]
 },
 GeoBackground -> None,
 GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular",
 GeoCenter -> {0, 180}
 ]
```

Comment: Here's a nice alternative: `GeoGraphics[{GrayLevel[1, 0], Tooltip[CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"], #] & /@ CommonName[CountryData[]]}, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["CountryBorders"], GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular", GeoRange -> "World"]`